# Generate a number-pattern in Java beginning with different numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, numbers

I am preparing for my exam from programming. And I am stuck on this task, I understand logic of patterns ( *at least I think so* ) but I can't figure out how to solve this.

Output for input `a = 6` needs to be like :

```
012345
123456
234567
345678
456789
567890
```

Output for input `a = 3` needs to be like :

```
012
123
234
```

Output for input `a = 4` needs to be like :

```
0123
1234
2345
3456
```

But I'm getting this :

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
2 3 4 5 
3 4 5 
4 5 
5
```

Here's my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++) {

    for (int j = i; j < a; j++) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I doubt that's *the* problem, but what's with the double braces?

Comment: By the way, you always need 6 (`a` I guess?) numbers on a line, not `a - i` numbers. And the numbers in each line always start at `i`, so...

Comment: What is the output for a = 2?

Comment: for a=3 output should be: 012 123 234

Comment: @KZukic [edit] your question please, posting the output in a comment will make it unreadable

Comment: I am sorry , that is what I got.

Comment: what will be the output for a = 10? Do the number need to be digits or can it be above 10?

Comment: No, the numbers should not get above 9 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make these changes to get the required output:

- Termination conditions of the outer `for` loop should be `i < a`;
- Termination conditions of the inner `for` loop should be `j < a + i`;
- The number you're printing should be not `j` but `j % 10` to satisfy the data sample you've provided (for input `a=6` it prints `0` as the last number on the very last line instead of `10`, that means we need not `j`, but only its rightmost digit which is the remainder of division by `10`).

That's how it can be fixed:

```
public static void printNumbers(int a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < a + i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j % 10 + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry , but for what is used % sign in this case?

Comment: @KZukic It's modulo operator, it allows to calculator the remainder of the division. For `10 % 10` you'll get `0` as your example requires.

Comment: @KZukic the modulus is used to extract the unit digit ( for example  12%10  will give you 2 -> and that is required if you look for input 6, the last line becomes 10 , there the answer is 0 )

Comment: I see now after testing it , thank you guys !

Comment: @KZukic Have a look this [*article*](https://www.baeldung.com/modulo-java) and this [*tutorial by Oracle*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Observations:**
Since it is a 2 dimensional output, we will need 2 loops ( one inside the other ).

Also, the starting point for each line is the value    from which the last line starts +1 .

If the value crosses 10, then we will keep the unit digit value only ( like in the last line). ( therefore we use modulus operator % that helps to extract the unit digit)

Code :

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 6;
        pattern(n);
    }

    private static void pattern(int n) {
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = k; j < k + n; j++) {
                System.out.print(j % 10);
            }
            k = i + 1;
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

and the answer is :

```
012345
123456
234567
345678
456789
567890
```

Comment: Yes sir, thank you , sorry I did not saw your answer at first, that is exactly what I was looking for.